# How to replace QUOTES like forums with php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I know I should probably be using preg_replace but I'm not the best with regex.  Could someone help me with the code for replacing [QUOTE=user]quote here[/QUOTE] to:

```
<p><b>user</b>quote here</p>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = '[QUOTE=user]quote here[/QUOTE]';

$regex = '/\[QUOTE=(.+)\](.+?)\[\/QUOTE\]/';
$replacement = '<p><b>$1</b>$2</p>';
$str = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $str);
```